# Call nested Azure logic app with get and body parameter

Tags: azure, get, nested, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

We are building nested logic apps where a logic app will call another logic app to aggregate some data.
Currently we have Logic Apps `A`, `B` and `C` all being setup with a GET request.
Logic App `ABC` that aggreagtes all the data will be exposed by the API over a GET request and internally call `A` to `C` to gather all the data.
When we use Postman however we get an error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "TriggerRequestMethodNotValid",
    "message": "The HTTP method for this request is not valid: expected 'Get' and actual 'POST'."
  }
}
```

Which would imply that `ABC` calls `A` with a POST instead of a GET.
We've got the hunch, that this is due to us calling the Logic App with a `body` element.
We temporarly fixed the problem by setting all logic app calls to `POST`, but we would like to avoid this, since we might expose `A` as system layer API and would like to keep it as a GET.
The code for `A`:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Filter_is_null": {
                "actions": {
                    "Get_locations": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['salesforce']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('Location__c'))}/items"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Response": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@body('Get_locations')?['value']",
                            "statusCode": 200
                        },
                        "kind": "Http",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_locations": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Response"
                    }
                },
                "else": {
                    "actions": {
                        "Get_locations_filtered": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['salesforce']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",
                                "path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('Location__c'))}/items",
                                "queries": {
                                    "$filter": "@triggerBody()?['filter']"
                                }
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "ApiConnection"
                        },
                        "Response_error": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": {
                                    "component": "sf-locations-get",
                                    "message": "bad request - validate filter"
                                },
                                "statusCode": 400
                            },
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Get_locations_filtered": [
                                    "Failed"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "Response"
                        },
                        "Response_filtered": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": "@body('Get_locations_filtered')?['value']",
                                "statusCode": 200
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Get_locations_filtered": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "Response"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@triggerBody()?['filter']",
                                "@null"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "If"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "request": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "filter": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
        }
    }
}
```

Image of `A` for reference:
[image: API 'A']

Image of `ABC` for reference:
[image: API 'ABC']

Is there a possibility to call nested logic apps, containing a `body` using GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call another logic app from one logic app and pass a body to it.
If you are calling another logic app which triggers with a http request the method expected is generally POST. Try to pass the body and check if that helps in your case.

[image]

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-nested-logic-apps)

You may also check these and see if these suffices your requirement:

https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/nested-logic-apps

https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2016/04/19/the-ability-to-call-nested-logic-apps-directly-from-logic-apps-designer/

Answer (score 1):

Using a body in a GET request breaks the internet.

In short, this breaks the semantics that a resource-uri in combination with the headers is the cacheable key. When you add a body to the GET request, the caching ability is removed.

It is by design that you cannot and should not add a body to a GET request.

You should rethink your call setup and when you need to send a body, then you need to use other HTTP methods that do not break proper semantics. e.g. POST, PUT, etc.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1581925